# Custom Scroll view in cocos2d without using uikit

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scrollview

I currently need to create a custom scroll view without using UIKit's scrollview in cocos2d.
The best way, I think, is to create a separate layer and then add all my sprites to that layer. But I'm not sure how to receive touch events for all of the sprites. Is there a best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen CCScrollLayer?  It might not be suitable for you but maybe you can copy the way that it is picking up touches.

- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/develop/Extensions/CCScrollLayer
- http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/17118

There's another one here as well, not sure if it's a fork or an independent one:

- https://github.com/jerrodputman/CCKit

But I didn't have much success with any of these.  The bounce and other parts of the experience never feel right, so I go back to using UIScrollView to handle the touches.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue and I found the SWScrollView here:

https://github.com/saim80/Cocos2D-Extensions

met my needs better than CCScrollView. It acts more like the UIScrollView where as CCScrollView is more for paging from what I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice framework called CMMSimpleFramework.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/39018

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/60354

There are some sample videos, and the link to the repo is on those pages.

One of the classes is a scrolling layer that might do what you need.
To get the sample project to run, I had to comment out some game center authentication handler code that has changed, but after I did that the demo worked fine.